# How to make boundingRect() in an arc shape?

Tags: c++, qt

My class inherits from QGraphicsItem. I draw it with painter->drawArc, and I want to make the same bound for that object, but QpainterPath does not have such function as painter. arcTo it is not the same, because it has line from center.

Code (Width is a width of pen, so the collision is on the external border of arc.):

```
QRectF Circle::boundingRect() const
{
    QRectF rect( -radius, -radius, radius*2, radius*2);
    return rect;
}

QPainterPath Circle::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath path;
    path.arcTo(-radius-width, -radius-width, (radius+width)*2, (radius+width)*2, startAngle/16, spanAngle/16);
    return path;
}

void Circle::paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QPen pen;
    pen.setCapStyle(Qt::FlatCap);
    pen.setWidth(width);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->drawArc(boundingRect(), startAngle, spanAngle);

}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but `boundingRect()` is required to always return a **rect**angle. No way around that. Not sure what you need this for but I guess you need to find another way. Maybe someone here has a good suggestion if you could provide a bit more context.

Comment: That's way I used a `shape();`, but this function has to return a `QPainterPath`, and I don't know how to draw an arc with `QPainterPath` like I've done this with painter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`QPainterPath::arcTo`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainterpath.html#arcTo), but you have to move the current position in the start point of the arc, otherwise the arc will be connected to the current position with a line.

To move the current position in the start point, you can use [`QPainterPath::arcMoveTo`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainterpath.html#arcMoveTo)

Example

```
QPainterPath pp;
pp.arcMoveTo(rect, startAngle);
pp.arcTo(rect, startAngle, spanAngle);
```

Consider also to use [`QPainterPathStroker`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainterpathstroker.html) to give a thickness to the shape. And also add the pen width to the bounding rect

Example:

```
QRectF Circle::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(-radius - width, -radius - width, (radius + width) * 2, (radius + width) * 2);
}

QPainterPath Circle::shape() const
{
    QRectF rect(-radius, -radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
    QPainterPath path;
    path.arcMoveTo(rect, startAngle / 16);
    path.arcTo(rect, startAngle / 16, spanAngle / 16);
    QPainterPathStroker pps;
    pps.setCapStyle(Qt::FlatCap);
    pps.setWidth(width);
    return pps.makeStroke(path);
}

void Circle::paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QPen pen;
    pen.setCapStyle(Qt::FlatCap);
    pen.setWidth(width);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    QRectF rect(-radius, -radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
    painter->drawArc(rect, startAngle, spanAngle);

}
```